# animate.css and viewport checker with bootstrap new complications

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, animate.css

I cant get it working for some reason. I have been researching this for like 2 days now and still nothing. First I wanted to use it with `bootstrap`, then i changed hidden and visible class in `css` and also in custom.js file, still nothing. Tried many things, nothing. I thought i try a different approach and so i downloaded the zip file here, still nothing, again changed hidden and visible `css` and `j`s refs still nothing! Whats going on?? `Js` is enabled, demo is working online but when I download it, it will show all posts without animation. error message is `jQuery` is not defined pointing to this which is the first line of  the final `js` where you could define what effects you want

```
etc --> jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

[tutorial here](http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery/)

Comment: I uploaded tutorial zip to a temp website and it is working! If i preview it in firefox a chrome from dreamveawer it wont work, but if i upload it does.... can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is bootstrap already have the class name ".hidden".

Try this solution

In the css file add custom hidden class

```
.hideme{
 opacity:0;
}
.visible{
 opacity:1;
}
```

And on page load try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.scroll').addClass("hideme").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
            offset: 100
        });
    });
```